# architecture - should I combine many ad-hoc applications to a single application?

Tags: java, architecture

My main goal is providing a search application written in jquery that is based on solr. (For those who unfamiliar with solr, just assume its a rest api that can return search result.)
For this goal I wrote many small applications and servlets that each one does an ad-hoc task.
For example:

1. SearchApp - a jquery app in which an end user can perform searches.
2. SolrProxy - A java servlet that plays a proxy role between the SearchApp and solr. One of the things it does is logging the user request for later analysis.
3. StatsApp- a servlet that performs analysis of the user activity and returns a json with the data.
4. Indexer - a java application that indexes data to solr according to my requirements. in this process it also fetches an SQLServer DB, and then performs some update commands to the DB.
5. IndexerServlet - an asynchronous servlet that uses Indexer to provide an ability to execute index by http request.
6. Nutch - an open source project that indexes data to solr for other requirements that are not accomplished in Indexer(3).
7. (MAYBE) - some service that will perform scheduled Nutch running.

And more components might be added.

It seems a bit wrong to have multiple java projects that each one does a single task, instead of having one project that handles most of the components.
Any ideas and insights on this?
Should I combine all the java apps to a single project? should I use some kind of a fremework for this? or should I live it as it is now?

Comment: Quick Idea: Implement a business facade which exposes services and delegates the calls to the proper "module" (in this case, each module is one of your current apps), passing the results to the service customer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's a bad idea that you have all these separate applications. They all seem to be doing one thing, and doing it well. What you *can* do, is expose them via a unified interface. So essentially you have a facade that sits in front of all these disparate services that presents an abstract and uniform interface. The consumers of this service will have no idea what sits behind that facade. This is just as well, because now you can discretely update and replace individual components without affecting others. If you had combined all of them into one, you would have to push a new release every time you modified one of the components.

Comment: How can I achieve this technically? Do I have one servlet that routes between all the other services?

Comment: @user1997656 That would work, though it might be better to expose it as service calls via XML-RPC, or SOAP, or via REST*like* interface.